# Server to run a long exe compiled in c++

Tags: c++

I have a long program compiled in c++, it take as income ad servers txt and the output is a single txt. The problem is the exe compiled take a long time to complete (5 hours) and I need to make a lot of test.

Can I run my exe program (with its files) in a server online with a faster CPU than mine.

Grettings,

Comment: _"Can I run my exe program (with its files) in a server online with a faster CPU than mine."_ Sure, but you probably need to pay for that service.

Comment: I'm not an expert on c++ but this sounds like a high coupling issue to me. Perhaps you could try and encapsulate your executable into smaller modules and test these individually?

Comment: If your program is strictly serial then not likely. Nowadays "faster CPU" pretty means "more CPU".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Azure Virtual Machines (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/) or Amazon's Windows Server Hosting (https://aws.amazon.com/windows/). Depending on whether your C++ program is Windows-only or not, you might also have some other alternatives (cloud-based mostly).

What all these solutions have in common is that they allow you to tune your virtual machine to allocate it more resources and thus be better from the performance point of view (which in turn will cost more).